# PHP - explode() not working with space delimiter

Tags: php

Now this should be simple, sure I'm doing smt stupid here.

I'm trying to divide a string made of a number and currency, into an array with one cell having the number, and another the currency. Not rocket science, right?

My code is smt as follows:

```
var_dump($valueWithCurrency);
var_dump(explode(" ", $valueWithCurrency));
```

Now the result of var_dump are as follows:

```
string(11) "-50,00 kr."
```

and

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(11) "-50,00 kr."
}
```

I tried a million different variations, nothing working. My question is, why the simple explode isn't splitting the string by spaces??

Comment: Maybe it is no "space" character. You could try `preg_split('/\s+/', $valueWithCurrency)`

Comment: `-50,00 kr.` should have 10 bytes not 11. You have something else in that string.

Comment: @MarkusZeller tried this, not working unfortunately

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález makes sense, but what can it be, and how should this affect my usage of explode() function

Comment: Did you try to copy the character between 0 and k and paste it in the explode function?

Comment: @Michael didnt think of that honestly. But tried that now upon your suggestion. Not working unfortunately as well :/

Comment: I can't know. To discover it, you can use an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it/), inspect with [bin2hex()](https://php.net/bin2hex) or use [Unicode Inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect). I matters because `explode()` uses the raw bytes, not the rendered view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a non-breaking space between the number and the currency (as it should be). You may solve your problem by using the hexadecimal coding of non-breaking space:

```
explode("\xc2\xa0", $valueWithCurrency)
```